# mm/dd/yy TO DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have been trying to convert this:

```
ReceiveDate
07/01/15
07/02/15
```

into this:

```
ReceiveDate
2015-07-01
2015-07-02
```

I have tried with:

```
try_convert(date,SRD.ReceiveDate,103)
try_convert(date,SRD.ReceiveDate,101)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: where does this data start from ?  a varchar field?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(10), SRD.ReceiveDate, 120)
```

Comment: This will also work on older versions of SQL server.

Comment: Here's the MSDN documentation too. I've always found it very helpful as the magic numbers relating to various date-masks are almost impossible to remember. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: @Xedni See the snippet I posted here.   I too can't keep them all straight.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
try_convert(date,SRD.ReceiveDate,1)
```

The format numbers you referenced do not match the input, here are the relevant number values and date formats:

```
1   - mm/dd/yy
101 - mm/dd/yyyy
103 - dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not intended as an Answer**, but, regarding Xedni's comment, this is a little something I use:

```
------ Convert Dates
;with cte as (
    Select Conv = N
          ,AsDateTime = try_convert(nvarchar(30),GetDate(),N)
          ,AsDate     = try_convert(nvarchar(30),convert(date,GetDate()),N)
          ,AsTime     = try_convert(nvarchar(30),convert(time,GetDate()),N)
     From  (Select Top 200 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values ) N
)
Select * 
 From  cte
 Where AsDateTime is not null 
    or AsDate     is not null 
    or AsTime     is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Nice, that is going into my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with mjsqu answer.

In addition to that, for more `date-format` options and to deal with possible input formatting issues (if the input is varchar), you can also try something like:

```
DECLARE @dateValue VARCHAR(20)='07/01/15'

SELECT TRY_CONVERT( DATE, @dateValue, 1) DateValueConvert;

SELECT TRY_PARSE(@dateValue AS DATE USING 'en-us') DateValueUS

SELECT TRY_PARSE(@dateValue AS DATE USING 'en-gb') DateValueGB
```

with output:

[image]